# Adding .split into my code

Tags: java, console-application

I'm creating a console program in Java with an array, I need to enter all of my code on one line in the following format up to 100 times.

car_make_name : car_model_name : car_model_tax : car_model_price

It's two strings and two int variables, I have code written out but I don't know how to use .split to enter the correct information into the corresponding variable.

This is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        //Arrays declared
          String[] cars = new String[20];
          String[] car_model_name = new String[20];
          int[] car_model_tax = new int[20];
          String[] car_make_name = new String[20];
          int[] car_model_price = new int[20];



          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

          //Loop??
          while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           String line = scanner.nextLine();
           if (line.equals("quit", "QUIT", "Quit")) {

           }

          }
            break;

            for (int x = 0; x < cars.length; x++){
                   System.out.println("Enter details, separating each with a ':' ");
                   cars[x] = System.console().readLine();

            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Is your question just "how to use split in general," or are you asking how to extract different data types from the same string (the strings and ints)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you may prefer [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) but not array to store your information if you read input from console and you can't control the input length of your user.

Second, you may want to use [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to split and convert it if necessary.

```
    System.out.println("Enter details, separating each with a ':' ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("quit")) {
            break;
        }
        final String[] split = line.split(":");
        // handle it
    }
```

Third, A good book can improve your programming level so much.If you have no experience of programming, I recommend *Head First Java*. Otherwise, I recommend *Thinking In Java*.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question, but it's possible that the issue is not only "how to use split," but also (or just), "how to extract different data types when split actually returns an array of strings."